# bad data structure cause "Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation"

Tags: transactions, blockchain, p2wpkh

i could not fix the problem using available answer for this error on BSE. [this is my previous transaction](https://mempool.space/tx/ef7d947fe4436a966ee27a430ec6474ac2004323a78686fd9bdc4dec2e53fe14#flow=&vout=1). i test alot of different data structure which was said to be the correct one but i got `Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation` error each time.

this is my raw unsigned transaction:

```
01000000
01
14fe532eec4ddc9bfd8686a7234300c24a47c60e437ae26e966a43e47f947def
00000000
16
00145951ac8720b1865ba633d19eaa6473afae7c46b3
ffffffff
02
c409000000000000
16
00140429fc6e543ff7b4b75d0c6a60013c125827aa66
dc05000000000000
16
00145951ac8720b1865ba633d19eaa6473afae7c46b3
00000000
01000000
```

this is my signed transaction and i sign the double `hash` of `sha2-256` of above raw unsigned transaction:

```
01000000
0001
01
14fe532eec4ddc9bfd8686a7234300c24a47c60e437ae26e966a43e47f947def
00000000
00
ffffffff
02
c409000000000000
16
00140429fc6e543ff7b4b75d0c6a60013c125827aa66
dc05000000000000
16
00145951ac8720b1865ba633d19eaa6473afae7c46b3

02
48
30
45

02
21
008bf85387dbea5c2fac2420f4a6e30be4f1859958809f8ff31f8d8d1bb4c73a25
02
20
1fca2d662eb187918ad2154c1ac0a71550626b235b4a6ad12919c8d6a88df48401
21
0280a1bfa268074c9171ed0e30f332706789c5138e1428e92506e671b1997eb874
00000000
```

which part of raw unsigned data structure is wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: This error almost certainly means that your signature is just invalid.